# SD card detection issue in WEC7

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I have purchased Openboard-AM335x board for development purposes for WIN CE platform.

I have gone through online guide to install WINCE on this board. I have installed visual studio, platform builder (WIN EC7), Phytec SDK (PD-13.2.0) and BSP. With this setup, i am able to create NK.bin file and load it to board.

My real problem is, SD card is not detected inside WIN CE OS. I have tried various options related to SDHC and SD BUS in catalog items inside visual studio. But have no luck, still it didn't work.

Please provide your suggestion/guidelines to solve this issue. Waiting for your feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you included the "Device Drivers\SD\SD Bs" and "Device Drivers\SD Clients\SD Memory" components that you can find in the catalog under "Core OS\Windows Embedded" and the BSP-specific SD host driver. To access the SD card you'll have to include also the FAT filesystem that you can find under "File System and Data Store\Storage Manager". 
If this doesn't solve your issue you can try to build a debug image and check the debug messages generated when you plug the SD card in.